# Responsive cell select in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm playing around with an idea for a responsive calendar.

Here's a fiddle that goes some way to illustrating what I'm thinking about...

http://jsfiddle.net/7fsyaowh/

The intended behaviour is as follows:

A user is presented with a row of dates. Some are class 'a' ('available'), and some are class 'b' ('booked').

The user can Select a start date and, optionally, an end date. The user can only select a date if it's class a. (If a user doesn't select an end date, that means the booking is for one day only).

When a user selects a start date, all the dates prior to that date become unavailable. Additionally all the dates after the next class b date also become unavailable, so the only available dates are those immediately following the first selected date.

I just can't think how to convey this behaviour in js (other than perhaps by assigning a distinct class id to each group of consecutive 'class a' dates).

Any thoughts appreciated.

There are other considerations, like what happens if a user selects the start date again, or a date between the start and end date, and some sort of prompt so the user knows what they're supposed to be doing at any given point, but I'll come to that later.

Contrary to what the fiddle suggests, there should be no drag-select behaviour.

html

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="our_table">
  <tr>
  <td class="a">1</td>
  <td class=a>2</td>
  <td class=a>3</td>
  <td class=a>4</td>
  <td class=a>5</td>
  <td class=b>6</td>
  <td class=a>7</td>
  <td class=b>8</td>
  <td class=a>9</td>
  <td class=a>10</td>
  <td class=a>11</td>
  <td class=a>12</td>
  <td class=b>13</td>
  <td class=a>14</td>
  <td class=a>15</td>
  <td class=b>16</td>
  <td class=a>17</td>
  <td class=a>18</td>
  <td class=a>19</td>
  <td class=a>20</td>
  <td class=a>21</td>
  <td class=b>22</td>
  <td class=a>23</td>
  <td class=a>24</td>
  <td class=a>25</td>
  <td class=a>26</td>
  <td class=a>27</td>
  <td class=b>28</td>
  <td class=a>29</td>
  <td class=a>30</td>
  </tr>
</table>
Submit
Clear/Reset
```

js/jquery

```
$(function () {
  var isMouseDown = false,
    isHighlighted;
  $("#our_table td")
    .mousedown(function () {
      isMouseDown = true;
      $(this).toggleClass("a");
      isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("a");
      return false; // prevent text selection
    })
    .mouseover(function () {
      if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("a", isHighlighted);
      }
    });

  $(document)
    .mouseup(function () {
      isMouseDown = false;
    });
});
```

css

```
table td {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:#def;
  border:1px solid #fff;
}

table td.a {
  background-color:#ddd;
}
table td.b {
  background-color:#bbc;
}
```

Comment: You can store each day as the days since the year 2000. This allows you to do comparisons to see which dates come before others etc. Why don't you hold a list of class B dates, then filter out the entries less than the start date, then make sure the end date cant be greater than or equal to the minimum of what's left of the list. Also make sure the end date is greater than the start date, but what if the start date is just before a class B date?

Comment: @Harith If the start date is just before the class be date then the booking only lasts a day

Comment: True. If you're doing this for multiple months then the "days since 2000" method will be suitable, but if you're doing it for only one month just give each day a value from 1 - 30. That's the logic of it, to implement it is a different question.

Comment: @Harith It would be for two months, rolling. I'm assuming that no booking would be for more than a month - but I'm keeping it simple(r) for now

Comment: Start by checking the `event.currentTarget` in the mouseover handler. Abort if a b class is encountered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.prevAll()` and `.nextAll()` method of jquery to disable dates previous and date after the `b` class . Also , below code is just for selecting start date and  it highlights date available in `yellow` so here you need to write logic for selecting end dates from `available` dates .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//click on a class and unselect it to see how this works..
$("td.a").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected")
  //see if has class selected..
  if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
    //get all previous date disable them
    $(this).prevAll(".a:not('.b')").addClass("disabled")
    //get all date after `b` disable them
    $(this).nextAll(".b:first").nextAll(".a ").addClass("disabled")
    //added class for available dates ..
    $(this).nextAll(".a:not('.disabled')").addClass("avaible")
  } else {
    $("tr td").removeClass("disabled").removeClass("avaible")
  }
})
```

```css
table td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #def;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

table td.a {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

table td.b {
  background-color: #bbc;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: grey !important;
}

.avaible {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="our_table">
  <tr>
    <td class="a">1</td>
    <td class="a">2</td>
    <td class="a">3</td>
    <td class="a">4</td>
    <td class="a">5</td>
    <td class="b">6</td>
    <td class="a">7</td>
    <td class="b">8</td>
    <td class="a">9</td>
    <td class="a">10</td>
    <td class="a">11</td>
    <td class="a">12</td>
    <td class="b">13</td>
    <td class="a">14</td>
    <td class="a">15</td>
    <td class="b">16</td>
    <td class="a">17</td>
    <td class="a">18</td>
    <td class="a">19</td>
    <td class="a">20</td>
    <td class="a">21</td>
    <td class="b">22</td>
    <td class="a">23</td>
    <td class="a">24</td>
    <td class="a">25</td>
    <td class="a">26</td>
    <td class="a">27</td>
    <td class="b">28</td>
    <td class="a">29</td>
    <td class="a">30</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```